# How can i loop over large number of files in some sort of cyclic way?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I mean to loop from the big array of files only on the first 20 files in a backgroundworker to report them to the progresschanged event. And remove the 20 files form the array.

Then to make a break when it's getting to the completed event to start the backgroundworker again this time the loop should be continue from the last point and loop over the next 20 files from the array.

In this way somehow maybe it will not choke the hard disk or the system memory.
Not sure how to do it and if it's a good idea if it will improve anything but the idea is not to make one heavy work at once on the hard disk and memory but make it in small parts/tasks.

```
int countUploadMsg = 0;
        private void backgroundWorker2_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            MimeKit.HeaderList loaded = new MimeKit.HeaderList();
            List<string> test = new List<string>();
            int counter = 0;
            MimekitallLoadedMessages = new List<MimeKit.MimeMessage>();
            MimeKit.MimeMessage loadedMessage = null;
            DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(emailsDirectory);
            FileInfo[] files = di.GetFiles();

            for (int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
            {
                if (i == 20)
                    break;
                string uid = seenUids[0];
                loadedMessage = MimeKit.MimeMessage.Load(files[i].FullName);
                MimekitallLoadedMessages.Add(loadedMessage);
                downloaded.Add(seenUids[i]);
                counter += 1;
                int nProgress = counter * 100 / files.Length;
                backgroundWorker2.ReportProgress(nProgress);
            }
         }
```

progresschanged

```
private void backgroundWorker2_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            pbt1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
            pbt1.Text = e.ProgressPercentage.ToString() + "%";
            pbt1.Invalidate();
                ListViewCostumControl.lvnf.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(new string[]
            {
              MimekitallLoadedMessages[countUploadMsg].From.ToString(),         
              MimekitallLoadedMessages[countUploadMsg].Subject,                 
              MimekitallLoadedMessages[countUploadMsg].Date.ToString()      
            }));
       }
```

completed event

```
private void backgroundWorker2_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            backgroundWorker2.RunWorkerAsync();
        }
```

Comment: Use a BlockingCollection and two tasks (1. fill item from array to collection, 2. work on collection) to build a pipeline or look for DataFlow to build such a pipeline

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you want to take 20 files? Why not 10, 5, 40 or 100?

> the idea is not to make one heavy work at once on the hard disk and
>   memory

Then you should take the smallest part of the work at once. In your case this will be processing of the single file. So, just remove this part

```
            if (i == 20)
            break;
```

If this is to "heavy" then you can add `Thread.Sleep`

```
            loadedMessage = MimeKit.MimeMessage.Load(files[i].FullName);
            Thread.Sleep(someDelay);
            MimekitallLoadedMessages.Add(loadedMessage);
```

Or maybe add delay somewhere inside the `MimeKit.MimeMessage.Load` or `MimekitallLoadedMessages.Add`.

Comment: I was wondering how some years ago when using outlook express when i was running the outlook express it was loading the messages from the hard disk so fast ? After all when downloading all my messages about 6000 i don't want to download them every time over again i want to load them back from the hard disk. But i don't remember that in outlook express it was taking time to load them.